# Styling html email with customised font without using <style>

Tags: html, fonts

Is there a way to style your email with your own font without using style tags? The font that I would like to use is 'filson-pro' which is an adobe font but you can also download it for free. The font is currently being hosted on our AWS environment.

Unfortunately, the program I am using to generate my HTML emails form does not support style tags `<style>` all styling needs to be done inline.

I have tried the options below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="#" />

<!-- Did not display on all email clients -->
```

```html
<h1 style="@import url('#'); font-family: filson-pro;" />

<!-- Did not work -->
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. You need to use `<style>`.

There are many HTML email generators that will inline styles from within `<style>` tags, and also leave things like `@font-face` declarations and `@media` queries in place for the clients that do support them.

What program or build tool are you using to generate your HTML emails? Maybe it is overly-aggressively trying to prevent you from using `<style>` tags at all, as many email clients will need all the styles to be inlined.

Ideally, the it would leave your `<style>` tags in place, or at least the styles that can’t be inlined, and you should end up with something like:

```html
<!-- Ideally, this is left in place by your HTML email tool, since it can’t be inlined -->
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Example Sans';
  src: url('https://cdn.example.com/example-sans.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('https://cdn.example.com/example-sans.woff')  format('woff');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
</style>
```

…

```
<!-- Only `font-family` is appled inline, not `@font-face` -->
<h1 style="font-family: 'Example Sans'">My Headline</h1>
```

Then, email clients like Mail on iOS that [do support `@font-face`](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-font-face/), will still be able to load the font, even though other clients will ignore the `<style>` tag, or won’t support `@font-face`, or both.